# Отглагольные прилагательные или причастия

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, причастия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить, являются ли следующие слова отглагольными прилагательными или причастиями (без зависимых слов)

приготовленный ужин,
вписанный угол,
запертая дверь,
выученный урок,
сваренное яйцо,
взволнованный человек.

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы неправильно сформулировали вопрос, Анна. Вы спрашиваете, являются ли они **отглагольными**, так звучит вопрос. Наверно, Ваш вопрос в том, **чем** является соответствующее отглагольное слово в каждом случае, прилагательным или причастием. Поправьте меня, если всё же Вы и спрашивали первое. Но тут очевидно, что все они отглагольные.

Comment: Артем, не путайте человека. Вопрос, является ли некое определение *причастием* или *отглагольным прилагательным* - это классика жанра. Класса с седьмого о нем говорят.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас все причастия. Это же не "изысканный" из скрина, - вот там контекст всё определяет, см.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Отглагольные прилагательные образуются только от глаголов
>   несовершенного вида: кипяченое молоко от кипятить, жженая пробка от
>   жечь...

У Вас же везде совершенный вид, этого достаточно.

Подробности [тутъ](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=d1687a03-b71b-41c7-9bb8-f40a117abd46).

---

Да, на закуску от "[1 сентября](http://festival.1september.ru/articles/564876/)", вопрос-ответ:

– Какие причастия не образуются от глаголов совершенного вида?

– Действительные причастия настоящего времени; страдательные причастия
 настоящего времени.

---

После уточняющих комментариев Славы - пассаж о видах адъективации (превращении в прилагательное); на скрине рассмотрен пример со словом "взволнованный":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: взволнованный человек - отглагольное прилагательное.

Comment: _Серж: взволнованный человек - **отглагольное прилагательное**._ === Зализняк с Вами согласен. Я тоже.

Comment: Взволновать - совершенный вид: человек, который взволнован. Это согласно правилам, которые я процитировала.

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: Взволновать - совершенный вид... Это согласно правилам, которые я процитировала._ === Ну и что с того, что совершенный вид? Галина, в приведённых Вами _правилах_ есть это: 

_"Повторим и уточним: …если можно применить степени сравнения или… образовать от слов**о**" [ошибка не моя!] наречие на -О, то **это прилагательное**""_. === Наречие от _взволнованный_ мы образовать можем: _**взволнованно**_. Значит… прилагательное?

Comment: Слава, спасибо. Я нашла уточняющее правило - о частичной адъективации; дополню ответ.

Comment: См.: Человек, взволнованный событием - причастие. Но: взволнованный человек  - отглагольное прилагательное.